# Why Python prints output in console after program completion?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I try a simple code

```
import time

for i in range (1,6):
    print 'hiiiiii'
    time.sleep(1)
```

I get the output

```
#after 5 seconds of sleep
hiiiiii
hiiiiii
hiiiiii
hiiiiii
hiiiiii
```

How to get the output after each second,

```
hiiiiii
#after 1 sec
hiiiiii
#after 1 sec 
hiiiiii
#after 1 sec 
hiiiiii
#after 1 sec 
hiiiiii
```

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and it printed one output per sec.

Comment: The same here - works perfectly

Comment: I'm using VS code, will that might be the problem?.  When I run it on a python shell it works fine for me too.